# Prevent on-hold when playing or pausing video

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, html5-video

I'm building an Ionic app. I have a div with a video inside of it, and the video has controls="true". On the div, the Ionic on-hold directive is used. When playing or pausing the video (using a short tap), the on-hold directive is activated too, however. Is there any way to prevent this, or to detect that the event originated from clicking play or pause?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this directive in your div

```
<div data-tap-disabled="true" >
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Is there any way to know whether the tap originated from the video? Or to detect whether it's a tap and not a long press?